# Error converting string to datetime and send to Oracle DB

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, visual-studio-2012, oracle11g

I am unable to convert string "11/07/2014 12:00:00 AM" to DateTime. I have tried in many ways but something is going wrong here are 2 method which I used

1st Way

```
Dim dateTime As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("11/07/2014 12:00:00 AM")
```

it is returning a value  "#11/07/2014#"

2nd way 
when I try to parse using the below method it returns a error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime "

```
Dim datetime = DateTime.ParseExact("11/07/2014 12:00:00 AM", "dd-mm-yyyy hh24 mi ss.ff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Could any one suggest me a valid method. I have to send this DateTime to oracle DB to get data

Comment: Well in the first case it looks like it's probably worked already (although it's not clear whether you're trying to parse November 7th or July 11th, which really doesn't help) and in the second case you're currently trying to parse an empty string *and* the format looks nothing like it should according to your input data. How did you expect that to work? You should read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx for the format specifiers in .NET...

Comment: for whatever reason, if the time is 00:00:00 or 12:00:00 VS doesnt include it in the value display (Add a second to the string and it will show in VS); otherwise the first one may be correct.  Use Console.WriteLine and the time portion will display.

Comment: What does this have to do with `C#`?

Comment: Sorry about the typo I some how omitted the date string. I have added the Date in the 2nd part. It pops the exception with the date string. And in the 1st way which is mention. it returns with '#' in the start and the end. Does it come out like this all the time or am I doing any thing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From today's date I assume your string represents November 7th.

[`Convert.ToDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime.aspx) parses your string successfully if your string format is a standard date and time format pattern of your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx). If this parsing will success, that means `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` is a sandard date and time format patter of your `CurrentCulture`. I didn't understand where these `#` comes from. They are irrelevant about parsing operation.

Your 2nd way throws [`FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.FormatException.aspx) because from [`DateTime.ParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. **The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly.**

In your example, they don't match. You need to use `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` format instead.

```
Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("11/07/2014 12:00:00 AM", 
                                         "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811294/my-datetime-now-function-returns-is-something-wrong-with-my-visual-studio-or I dont know what is going wrong

Comment: @gnsanvesh Looks like `#` is just a representation of a `DateTime`. You shouldn't see it when you use DateTime object.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var datetime = DateTime.ParseExact("11/07/2014 12:00:00 AM", "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: It returns the same error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."