# My DateTime.Now function returns #. Is something wrong with my visual studio or something wrong in the declaration

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, visual-studio-2012

Is something wrong with my visual studio or am i missing something.  When ever i convert something into datetime these # add up. And i cannot send strings to the database to get data

[image: DateTime Error]

Comment: You can declare them like this too `Dim dt As DateTime = #11/7/2014 4:33:13 PM#`

Comment: you should begin accepting (click the check) answers which help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just VB's visual representation of DateTime literal. Never mind it, it's has a DateTime value - use it as such.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending strings to a database, my guess is you're not using parameters.  Try using a parameter and assigning the datetime to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it without the VB.NET date/time delimiters (the # symbols), just append the ToString method.

```
? Date.Now
#11/7/2014 5:42:40 PM#
? Date.Now.ToString
"11/7/2014 5:42:46 PM"
```